# How can overloaded 'operator new' cause infinite loops?

Tags: c++, overloading, infinite-loop, new-operator

I was reading a book named
"Hands-On System Programming with C++". It says on page 320 that overloading the `new` operator can cause infinite loops, so it should be avoided.

> These overloads affect all allocations, including those used by the C++ library, so care should be taken when leveraging these overloads as infinite cyclic recursions could occur if an allocation is performed inside these functions. For example, data structures such as std::vector and std::list, or debugging functions such as std::cout and std::cerr cannot be used as these facilities use the new() and delete() operators to allocate memory.

So, how can this piece of code cause an infinite loop, and why should I not use `cout` and `vector` with it? This was the piece of code in the book. I tried to use `vector`, `cout` (inside the `new` operator), `push_back`, but can't replicate the situation. So, when exactly can this happen?

```
void* operator new (size_t size){
    if(size > 1000) page_counter++;
    return malloc(size);
}
```

Comment: *infinite cyclic recursions could occur* -- The key word in that sentence is **could** occur, not **must** occur.

Comment: The fact something *may* happen doesn't mean it *will* happen.   Equally, when testing, the absence of a symptom does not always mean there is no flaw in the code.   Writing to `std::cout` would cause a problem if the write forced `std::cout` to reallocate its stream buffer.  Stream buffers will, practically with any reasonable implementation, only be reallocated occasionally, not by every output operation.

Comment: "can cause infinite loops, **so it should be avoided**" -- nonsense. There are lots of things that should be avoided **inside overloaded operator `new`**, but that's completely different. Basically, just call C functions and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply telling a `std::vector` to allocate some memory in `operator new` should do it:

```
void *operator new(std::size_t size) {
    // std::vector<int>::reserve calls std::allocator<int>::allocate calls (this) operator new calls ...
    std::vector<int>().reserve(999);
    return std::malloc(size);
}

int main() {
    int *p = new int(42);
    // OFC, this is undefined behavior, so we *could* reach this, but... we don't, which means it definitely is UB
    std::cout << "Shouldn't reach this!\n";
}
```

[Godbolt shows it crashing](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:17,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:17,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:7,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:7),source:%27%23include+%3Ccstddef%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccstdlib%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cnew%3E%0A%23include+%3Cvector%3E%0A%0Avoid+*operator+new(std::size_t+size)+%7B%0A++++//+std::vector%3Cint%3E::reserve+calls+std::allocator%3Cint%3E::allocate+calls+(this)+operator+new+calls+...%0A++++std::vector%3Cint%3E().reserve(999)%3B%0A++++return+std::malloc(size)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++int+*p+%3D+new+int(42)%3B%0A++++//+OFC,+this+is+undefined+behavior,+so+we+very+well+*could*+reach+this,+but...+we+don!%27t%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+%22Shouldn!%27t+reach+this!!%5Cn%22%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:56.208670095518,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1000,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B17%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+10.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.33333333333333,l:%274%27,m:45.840130505709624,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:2,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%232+with+x86-64+clang+10.0.0%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:54.15986949429037,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:43.791329904482,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Note that a) It's not enough to just construct a `std::vector`, because that might not allocate. `std::vector` usually only allocates when you somehow tell it to. It will expand when you try to add things to it, or you can say "be at least this big" with `reserve`. b) You have to call `operator new` from somewhere to trigger the loop (here it's within the `new` in `main`).

Comment: Ok, But why it doesn't happen with cout does cout allocate memory it needs on the stack or what's the difference

Comment: @ahmedamr I mean, why would `std::cout` or `operator<<` need to allocate dynamic memory? They're probably just wrappers around a C function, which doesn't even know about `operator new`. It's *allowed* for them to allocate, so they might, but at least Godbolt's implementation (compiler/standard lib/OS/computer/phase of the moon/etc.) doesn't, so using `std::cout` doesn't trigger it. `std::vector` *definitely* triggers it, because it's specified that it uses `operator new`.

Comment: @HTNW It's pretty easy to reproduce re-entry with `std::cout` as well by using a custom overload of `operator<<`. (That is not to say that the standard overloads are guaranteed to not use operator new)